# how can i use Parametrization in selenium IDE

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I have given a login page to test,I wish to test it using selenium IDE. Manually I tested the scenario with different login values. Which is the best way to test my scenario in selenium

Comment: Just a friendly tip, you may want to read over this page: [The How-To-Ask Guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you can always be sure that your questions are easily answerable and as clear as possible. Be sure to include any efforts you've made to fix the problem you're having, and what happened when you attempted those fixes. Also don't forget to your show code and any error messages!

Comment: The IDE is currently set up to do this type of data fed testing without plugins.
Though waht you COULD do is set up a test suite for code reuse:
variables1.html
login.html
variables2.html
login.html

Where you set username & password in each of the variables files and login.html uses those variables.
It's a hack, I know.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating an XML file (say testLogin.XML) that stores the logins you want to use

```
<testdata>
    <vars uname=”user1” pword=”password1”/>
    <vars uname=”user2” pword=”password2”/>
    <vars uname=”user3” pword=”password3”/>
</testdata>
```

In your test after you have opened the login page 
put in the following steps

```
<tr>
    <td>formXml</td>
    <td>location of testLogin.XML</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>type</td>
    <td>location of username field</td>
    <td>${uname}</td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>type</td>
    <td>location of password field</td>
    <td>${pword}</td>
</tr>
```

At the end of your test

```
<tr>
    <td>endforXml</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

I am fairly new to selenium and found this method that worked for my case.

Comment: This solution requires a plug-in, does it not?

Answer (score 0):

I currently use Stored Variables plugin for selenium ide which can be downloaded [here.](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stored-variables-viewer-seleni/) As for the documentation, you can see it [here.](https://willcodefor.wordpress.com/2013/05/07/creating-global-variables-in-selenium-ide/) Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways how to run the very same test with different values.

1) Use Stored Variables plugin and store values for the testcase into variables. Use multiple occurrences of the very same testcase in the same testsuite followed by case which will change values for stored variables for the next (but the same) testcase. All you need to do is to Add a test case from the very same. be careful when changing the test case, Selenium IDE has a bug in reloading the file for the other occurencies and you will need to exit IDE and Load it again.

2) Use **Selblocks** plugin to parametrize test case via XML file. The commands `ForXML` and `endForXML` will encapsulate the code you need to run in the cycle with different values from the XML. Names of variables are parameters of the XML tag just like this:

```
<testdata>
    <vars variable1=”xxx” variable2=”xxx” .. variableN="xxx" />
    ..
    <vars variable1=”xxx” variable2=”xxx” .. variableN="xxx" />
</testdata>
```

I recommend to make a log about each step result (passesd/failed) with `echo` command. You can later review the results via search the log file or

There is an option for negative testing, so you will be able to put there negative data which should end up with error, so you have to detect errors etc. SelBlocks has some other commands as `if` - `endIf`, which will help you to reach that point. You can send with each row of data the "expected" variables, which contain the information, how the test should end. Find complete reference of SelBlocks here: http://refactoror.wikia.com/wiki/Selblocks_Reference